# ERROR: Problems trying to get index of users! Integrate Drupal 7 and Moodle 2.4

Tags: drupal, cygwin, moodle

HI all I am the following error **ERROR: Problems trying to get index of users!**, when I try to run the script to synchronize users between Drupal and Moodle in cygwin it runs without problems and shows the total number of users I have on Drupal database, running the same script in my browser it shows me the error already cited, does any one  was able to overcame this problem?

Answer (score 0):

That script is only for running from the command line. I don't believe it is meant to work/will work running from the browser. I am actually getting the same error right now while trying to run from the command line, and I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why.